# Format a string to have the same number of characters in a shell posix script

Tags: shell, scripting, sh

I have various variables and what I want to do is to print them all with the same width (character wise). To achieve that, I first need to discover which is the longest string and add one to it,
and then print the shorter ones with that width, padding with spaces.

well ideally i want the output to be like

```
    IFROGZ FREE REIN 2 "00:00:00:00:B5:C8"
    Mi Phone           "A4:50:46:AC:32:59" 
    realme Watch       "D8:CA:8E:CD:5D:7C"
```

where in case of a device being connected on the left 2 of the 4 spaces become asterix(*) but this question is more adressed to the right padding/formating

`printf %15s $something ' ' $isuppose`, doesn't work which would be the ideal solution, but how do I find the width to put there?

A very important thing is it needs to be POSIX compliant scripting.

Here's where I'm at, but the code at this point is very redudant because I've tried brute-forcing the solution.

```sh
inc=$#
inc=$((inc-1))
demon=$(eval printf \"\$$inc\"); 
inc=$((inc-2))
tellar=$(eval printf \"\$$inc\"); 
demon=${demon:1:-1}$tella$tellar
inc=$((inc-1))
while (( $inc >= 2 )); do
    aussie=$(eval printf \"\$$inc\"); 
    inc=$((inc-2))
    tellar=$(eval printf \"\$$inc\"); 
    inc=$((inc+2))
    demon=$(printf "%s»%"$smoll"s%s" $demon ${aussie:1:-1} " " $tellar);
    inc=$((inc-3))
done
demon=$(echo $demon | sed -E "s/»/`space=${#demon}; while (( smoll > i++ )); do ( printf " " ); done; unset space;`\n/g")
```

Here's the current input and output although the input is "wrong".

[image: the output]

Comment: Is your example of input or of output? What does the other look like?

Comment: its an example of a pretended output

Comment: what is the input?

Comment: i edited the question to be more "visual" and easier on you guy's

Comment: You appear to have misunderstood my question. You are trying to format some input to produce some output. You have shown sample output but we have no idea what the input is. For example, what is the input that should produce the output: `[     - hello        | value is 3]` ? (wrapped with brackets to force backticks to work with leading spaces)

Comment: @jhnc i updated my question to adress more of the specific's, also although im doing fprint that fprint thing is not to "stdout" its "piped into demon so i can put the entire vector of string's on dmenu

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given a set of variables, the maximum width can be easily calculated with:

```
setwidth(){
    width=0
    for str in "$@"; do
        [ $width -lt ${#str} ] && width=${#str}
    done
}
```

We store the result in a global variable `width` for later use in a `printf` format string.

---

Example of use:

```
var1="123"
var2=" 2345"
var3="123456 89"

testprint(){
    setwidth "$@"
    echo right-justified:
    printf "\055 %${width}s |\n" "$@"
    echo
    echo left-justified:
    printf "\055 %-${width}s |\n" "$@"
}

testprint "$var1" "$var2" "$var3"
```

giving:

```
right-justified:
-       123 |
-      2345 |
- 123456 89 |

left-justified:
- 123       |
-  2345     |
- 123456 89 |
```

Comment: oh it work's maybe i was calculating $smoll wrong so the bottom code for me was irrelevant either way i feel gratefull